# Undefined method `year' for Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to select date by date_select, but in database I have query:

```
"DATE_INTEGRATION" LIKE '["2008", "8", "28"]%
```

I use Metasearch in my form:

```
<%= f.date_select :date_integration_sw %>
```

Error:

```
undefined method `year' for ["2008", "8", "28"]:Array
```

How i fix it?

I want to get `LIKE '2010-08-10%'`, or convert `<%= f.date_select :date_integration_sw %>`, to `2010-08-10` in `date_select`.

Comment: please put on some more clearification on your question..what your tried and what you got

Comment: are you calling `.year` anywhere in your code??

Comment: No year is the first select, how I convert `<%= f.date_select :date_integration_sw %>`, to 2010-08-10 in date_select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding monanik's answer, to turn the array into a `Date` object, do this:

```
Date.parse(["2008", "8", "28"].join('-'))
```

This returns an object that responds to the methods `year`, `month`, and `day`.

Comment: I try this `<%= f.datetime_select Date.parse(:date_integration_sw).join('-') %>`, but get `can't convert Symbol into String`

Comment: @Erihon1890 Yeah, that won't work. `:date_integration_sw` is not a variable you can pass around, it's more like a placeholder so that `f.date_select` knows which field you want displayed. Is `date_integration_sw` a DB field? How does the field end up being an array in your code?

Comment: Yes date_integration_sw is DB field

Answer (score -1):

Instade of Array, pass 'Date' or 'Datetime' to f.date_select